# Python regex expression , split the data by '=' character

Tags: python, regex

This is my data

```
text = 'name = steve age=23 city = usa address1 = - address2 = ca,2nd floor ,3rd aven. qualification = doctor'
```

and the pattern which I written `pattern=r'(\w+)\s*=\s*([-,\w]+)'` and getting below output.

match = re.findall(pattern,text)

```
[('name', 'steve'),
 ('age', '23'),
 ('city', 'usa'),
 ('address1', '-'),
 ('address2', 'ca,2nd'),
 ('qualification', 'doctor')]
```

The above result is not expected as address2 key have partial values. Expected output is 'ca,2nd floor ,3rd aven.' .

Comment: Use `(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\w+\s*=|$)`, see https://regex101.com/r/nClnZR/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\w+\s*=|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nClnZR/1). *Details*:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` char enclosed with optional whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\w+\s*=|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires either zero or more whitespaces + one or more word chars + zero or more whitespaces + `=`, or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1gE1cn):

```py
import re
text = 'name = steve age=23 city = usa address1 = - address2 = ca,2nd floor ,3rd aven. qualification = doctor'
print(re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\w+\s*=|$)', text))
```

Output:

```
[
    ('name', 'steve'),
    ('age', '23'),
    ('city', 'usa'),
    ('address1', '-'),
    ('address2', 'ca,2nd floor ,3rd aven.'),
    ('qualification', 'doctor')
]
```